# How long do you need after handing a PSD file with the final design, to the final page (in days)?

Tags: psd

I applied for a job, the boss wrote me back and made me two questions:

One of them is:

How long do you need after handing a PSD file with the final design, to the final page (in days)?

Can somebody please help me to understand the question because I think it's not that clear!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Fuser97381 That may be, but both the original question and this question is clearly off-topic for SO. Try another SE site.

Comment: I was being sardonic.